# How to send UIBezierPath with Game Center sendDataToAllPlayers

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, nsdata, gamekit

I have a game that sends data from one player to all players. I can't figure out how to send a UIBezierPath object. I'm archiving the UIBezierPath object into NSData.

Here is the data struct that I use to send and receive data:

```
struct DataStruct {
    var action: Action = Action.Nil
    var point: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    var path: NSData = NSData()
    var speed: CGFloat = 0.0
}
```

Without the NSData in the Struct, everything works. With it, I am able to send the data but unable to receive and getBytes(). I cannot figure out how to encode and decode it. It makes sense since the sizeof() of the DataStruct is not the correct size of the data sent. But I can't find an example of this. Any example or help is greatly appreciated. I have limited experience with sending and receiving data.

Here is my function to archive and send it:

```
func sendData(action: Action, point: CGPoint, path: UIBezierPath, speed: CGFloat, mode: GKMatchSendDataMode) {
    // update player position, velocity and angle
    let pathData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(path)
    var dataStruct = DataStruct(action: action, point: point, path: pathData, speed: speed)
    let data: NSData = NSData(bytes: &dataStruct, length: sizeof(DataStruct))
    do {
        try GameCenterMatch.sendDataToAllPlayers(data, withDataMode: mode)
        print("data sent: \(dataStruct)")
    } catch {
        print("data sent error")
    }
}
```

Here is part of my function to receive it:

```
    func match(match: GKMatch, didReceiveData data: NSData, fromRemotePlayer player: GKPlayer) {
    if GameCenterMatch == match {
        var dataStruct = DataStruct()
        data.getBytes(&dataStruct, length: sizeof(DataStruct))
        print("data received: \(player.displayName), data: \(dataStruct)")
```

Answer (score 2):

I've not done this, but one thing that stands out is you're sending a byte array when some of the content (path) is just a pointer to another byte array. You would get the same problem with String, as the sizeOf DataStruct is constant and does not include the content of referenced content like NSData, String, objects, etc., only their pointer.

You should archive DataStruct, and send that and unarchive at the other end.

Comment: i'll give it a try. assume i have to implement NSCoding for the struct and change it to a class?

Comment: You could do that or create a DataStructHelper class that implements NSCoding and archives a DataStruct.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Michael's suggestion, I created a class to encode and decode and it works! Hopefully this will help others in the future.

```
class DataClass: NSObject, NSCoding {
var action: ActionType
var point: CGPoint
var path: UIBezierPath
var speed: CGFloat

override init() {
    self.action = ActionType.Nil
    self.point = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    self.path = UIBezierPath()
    self.speed = 0.0

    super.init()
}
init(action: ActionType, point: CGPoint, path: UIBezierPath, speed: CGFloat) {
    self.action = action
    self.point = point
    self.path = path
    self.speed = speed

    super.init()
}

// MARK: NSCoding
required convenience init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
    let action = ActionType(rawValue: decoder.decodeIntegerForKey("action")) ?? .Nil
    let point = decoder.decodeCGPointForKey("point")
    let path = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("path") as! UIBezierPath
    let speed = CGFloat(decoder.decodeFloatForKey("speed"))

    self.init(
        action: action,
        point: point,
        path: path,
        speed: speed
    )
}

func encodeWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {
    coder.encodeInteger(action.rawValue, forKey: "action")
    coder.encodeCGPoint(self.point, forKey: "point")
    coder.encodeObject(self.path, forKey: "path")
    coder.encodeFloat(Float(self.speed), forKey: "speed")
}
```

}